Disable Spring JPA Logback DEBUG messages for JpaTransactionManager and AbstractPlatformTransactionManager
If there's a custom Transaction Manager extending JpaTransactionManager, it seems impossible to suppress the DEBUG messages from these two classes.
**org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager**

Logback invokes the parent's logging by default for every registered child but it's possible to disable it with usual configuration. Not with these two Spring classes, however.
2024-11-20 10:29:26,311 DEBUG [http-nio-80-exec-5] o.s.o.j.JpaTransactionManager: Opened new EntityManager [SessionImpl(1432231711<open>)] for JPA transaction
2024-11-20 10:29:26,311 DEBUG [http-nio-80-exec-9] o.s.o.j.JpaTransactionManager: Exposing JPA transaction as JDBC [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$HibernateConnectionHandle@7bf2a646]
...
2024-11-20 10:29:26,312 DEBUG [http-nio-80-exec-8] o.s.o.j.JpaTransactionManager: Found thread-bound EntityManager [SessionImpl(632462581<open>)] for JPA transaction
2024-11-20 10:29:26,312 DEBUG [http-nio-80-exec-9] o.s.o.j.JpaTransactionManager: Found thread-bound EntityManager [SessionImpl(269177489<open>)] for JPA transaction
2024-11-20 10:29:26,312 DEBUG [http-nio-80-exec-8] o.s.t.s.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager: Participating in existing transaction
...
2024-11-20 10:29:26,318 DEBUG [http-nio-80-exec-9] o.s.t.s.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager: Initiating transaction commit
2024-11-20 10:29:26,318 DEBUG [http-nio-80-exec-8] o.s.o.j.JpaTransactionManager: Committing JPA transaction on EntityManager [SessionImpl(632462581<open>)]
2024-11-20 10:29:26,318 DEBUG [http-nio-80-exec-9] o.s.o.j.JpaTransactionManager: Committing JPA transaction on EntityManager [SessionImpl(269177489<open>)]
2024-11-20 10:29:26,319 DEBUG [http-nio-80-exec-8] o.s.o.j.JpaTransactionManager: Closing JPA EntityManager [SessionImpl(632462581<open>)] after transaction
2024-11-20 10:29:26,319 DEBUG [http-nio-80-exec-9] o.s.o.j.JpaTransactionManager: Closing JPA EntityManager [SessionImpl(269177489<open>)] after transaction

The Transaction Manager is defined like this. Even if it doesn't have any logging code inside, the above messages trickle through anyway.
package my.package;
public class MyTransactionManager extends JpaTransactionManager {
...

Log level is DEBUG for "my.package". This is important. If the level goes above to INFO, it shuts up Spring JPA messages. Nothing else does, unfortunately.
<logger name="**my.package**" level="debug" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
    <appender-ref ref="Console" />
</logger>

Tried various Logback tricks with filters and No-op appenders to no avail.
<appender name="DENY_ALL" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
        <level>OFF</level>
    </filter>
</appender>

<appender name="NOOP" class="ch.qos.logback.core.helpers.NOPAppender"/>

<logger name="org.springframework" level="OFF"/>
<logger name="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" level="OFF" additivity="false"/>
<logger name="org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager" level="OFF" additivity="false"/>
<logger name="my.package.MyTransactionManager" level="OFF"/>

<logger name="org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager" level="OFF" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="DENY_ALL"/>
</logger>

<logger name="org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager" level="OFF" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="NOOP"/>
</logger>

<logger name="org.springframework" level="OFF" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="DENY_ALL"/>
</logger>

<root level="info">
    <appender-ref ref="DENY_ALL"/>
</root>

Any thoughts how to get rid of this spam?

The logger is based on the actual class -> protected transient Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass()); this is the line that creates the logger. So there can be only JpaTransactionbManager log lines if there is such a class. Also are you sure you are using Logback and not for instance log4j2 or something else? Are you using Spring Boot?

No references to log4j2. Apache Commons Logging and default Spring Boot 3.3.2 Logback implementation (ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.5.6). Logback responds well to any configuration instructions except for the two offending classes. I even created a fake parent-child couple but that parent's log instructions can be properly managed by Logback. There are entries for both JpaTransactionManager and AbstractPlatformTransactionManager in the output and, actually, it's a typical compressed Logback format so no other logging implementation seems directly involved here.

Well as mentioned the class is added dynamic so it will create a logger for MyTransactionManager. So unless you are running with multiple transaction managers there should be no logging. The only thing I can think of is that you are messing with classloaders or something alike. Have you tried ditching your logback.xml and just use the application.properties to configure the logging?

Nope. It's the same regardless if configured via XML or properties. I prefer %class but %logger behaves similarly.
logging.level.org.springframework=OFF
logging.level.org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager=OFF
logging.level.my.package=DEBUG
logging.level.root=INFO
logging.pattern.console=%date{ISO8601} %highlight(%-5level) %magenta([%thread]) %class{50}: %msg%n%throwable

Tried Spring Boot from 3.0.0 to 3.3.5 with the same results. Everything is manageable except these two culprits. A very basic application at this point, no low-level hacks or undocumented features.
